# How to delete till a specific word?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have a bunch of text, say:

```
This is some sample text. I would like to delete this text.
```

The question is how do I delete *till* a specific word. If my cursor is at the start of the above sentence, and I say to delete till the word "text", this should be the result:

```
text. I would like to delete this text.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can delete by searching (`:h /`):

```
d/text
```

It will wrap around the line and delete in any following line where "text" exists. If that is undesired then we have to resort to `:h :substitute`. (There are ways to use `/` to `d`elete; see below.)

```
:s:\v.{-}\zetext::e
```

The above command will remove all characters preceding the word "text" from the current line. If the line does not contain the word "text," it will simply do nothing. For explanation, see `:h :s`, `:h /\v`, `:h /\{-`, `:h /\ze`, and `:h :s_e`.

---

[Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343) says, "You can still use a search if you only want to search on the current line, by matching the current cursor position: `d/\%#.*\zstext`. Or yet another technique: `V<Esc>d/\%Vtext`. This one works by only matching in the most recent visual selection."

Comment: Actually it will error, but the e flag (i think) suppresses that

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, right; incorporated.

Comment: You can still use a search if you only want to search on the current line, by matching the current cursor position: `d/\%#.*\zstext`

Comment: Yet another technique! `V<Esc>d/\%Vtext`. This one works by only matching in the most recent visual selection. Vim is so cool.